# In MS Access VBA, how do I call a stored append query with parameters?

Tags: ms-access, vba, parameters

In my Access 2007 database, I've got an append query with parameters in it. How do I call this query from a VBA script?

I realize that I could just generate the query text on the fly in the VBA code, but that's much more awkward.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the following to work:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qry As DAO.QueryDef

Set db = CurrentDb

Set qry= db.QueryDefs("NameOfMyStoredQuery")

qry.Parameters(0) = FirstParamValue
qry.Parameters(1) = SecondParamValue
qry.Parameters(2) = ThirdParamValue

qry.Execute
```

Comment: You should also be able to use the Parameter names

Comment: Also consider `qry.Execute dbFailOnError` and add an error hander to your procedure.